# How do I Secure a `credential.json` file in a Production Server

Tags: python, django, api

I am connecting to a google service via a (downloaded)`credential.json` file, following is my snippet:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'credential.json'))
```

this is working perfectly, however I want to to use the file in my production server, but I know it is not a good practice to upload API file/key to a production server, I am using python-decouple package to store my other keys, and using it as environment variables in the production server.

My question is how do I use a 'file' and its key contents securely in a production server?

I tried using python-decouple package, it works perfectly on individual keys, but on files I cannot managed to make it work.

Comment: I've had good luck with storing credentials like that in a service like Google Secret Manager. Although, since you need a credential file to access it, it doesn't get rid of all of your secrets. But going from many secrets to one secret is still an improvement.

Comment: thanks, will check google secret manger for more info.

Comment: you can also use `AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store`